# Spark 1.6 and compute stats

Tags: apache-spark, hive, impala

When using underlying parquet files of tables from spark1.6 , does compute stats still helps ?  Ex:

```
 hiveCtx.read.format("parquet")
        .load("/path/*.parquet").registerTempTable("TEST")
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on various cases

- whether your table is partitioned and if it is partitioned then are you reading one partition or all in one sort.
- If your table is partitioned then always advisable to read from table as Hive OR Impala maintains metadata and to create dataframe in spark with associated data will make your code perform better when you apply some transformation on Spark DF.
- I can see you are using hiveContext to read your parquet file, performance wise it'll only have small deflection but overall no much difference.

Comment: thanks for quick one, yes , table is partitioned and reading a partition at a time from TEMP table registered. this way partition pruning is working fine. But still not sure underlying stats helps here..

Comment: definitely this is not a better approach to start with, if table is partitioned then always read the table instead of a separate file from any partition. you can use lazy val while creating df which will help not compute immediately but to when needed.

Comment: Agree, would want to avoid compute stats if this works well without the stats (taking much time) due to n number of jobs part of batch and batch completion is crossing specified timeline.